# Calculate prior ties individuals have had with other team members prior to current team

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, count

I want to calculate the number of prior ties each member has had with other team members prior to the formation of the current team.

I have the following table

```html
TeamId UserId Date
1     100   2/1/2017 
1     101   2/1/2017
1     102   2/1/2017 
2     100   2//1/2016
2     105   2//1/2016
3        100   2//1/2015
3     101   2//1/2015
3        102   2//1/2015
3        105   2//1/2015
3     106   2//1/2015
4     101   1/3/2015
4     102   1/3/2015
4     105   1/3/2015
4        106   1/3/2015
```

I want to get the following table

```html
TeamId number of previous collaborations
1        4
2         1
3        6
4         0
```

For example for team 1: 
user 100 has collaborated with user 101 once in team 3 and with user 102 once  in team 3therefore = 1+1=2
user 101 has collaborated with user 102 twice (once in team 3 and once in team 4)= 1+1=2

so the number of previous collaborations for this team is 4.

I do not know how to write the code. any help is appreciated

```html
SELECT [TeamId],
COUNT( SELECT [Date] FROM [submissions] s1
       WHERE s.[UserId] = [submissions].[UserId]
       AND [Date]< [submissions].[Date]
       ORDER BY [DateSubmitted] DESC) as Num_Collaborations
     )
FROM [submissions]
```

Comment: Challenging question. This link should get you started... i just don't have any more time to work on it. Focus on the results, not the code. Once you understand those, you can work out your next bit of code from the cte filtered.  http://rextester.com/OSS61370

Comment: Thanks @scsimon. I used your code to produce my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much @scsimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a challenging problem. You have to include the same table 4 times in the query:

```
select t1.TeamId, t1.UserId, t2.TeamId as OtherTeam, t3.UserId as Collaborator
from @table t1, @table t2, @table t3, @table t4
where t1.UserId = t2.UserId and
      t2.TheDate < t1.TheDate and
      t3.TeamId = t2.TeamId and
      t4.TeamId = t1.TeamId and
      t4.UserId = t3.UserId and
      t4.UserId < t1.UserId
```

http://rextester.com/LHZS40204

(then you can group by and count to get the final result)

Comment: Thank you so much @Remi. It gives the right answer. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I edited my answer: the != condition was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the user collaborations with a self-join:

```
select s.userid, s2.userid as userid2, s.date,
       row_number() over (order by (select null)) as c_id
from submissions s join
     submissions s2
     on s2.teamid = s.teamid;
```

Let's use this as a subquery to answer your question. The idea is to match the collaborations back to the submissions -- with the constraint that the two users are on the same team at a *later* date.  Then, you can aggregate:

```
with c as (
      select s.userid, s2.userid as userid2, s.date,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as c_id
      from submissions s join
           submissions s2
           on s2.teamid = s.teamid
     )
select s1.teamid, count(distinct c_id) as num_previous_collaborations
from c c join
     submissions s1
     on s1.userid = c.userid and
        s1.date > c.date join  -- they are later on a team
     submissions s2
     on s2.userid = c.userid2 and
        s2.teamid = s1.teamid 
group by s1.teami;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gorden. I appreciate your speedy help.

Comment: c will have each pair of users twice, and pairs of identical users. Don't you need a condition such as s.userid < s2.userid to avoid counting a collaboration twice? I had to include such a condition in my solution.

Comment: @Rémi . . . As the question is stated, it seems they should be counted twice ("calculate the number of prior ties each member has had with other team members prior to the formation of the current team").  Admittedly the sample data suggests your interpretation.  The additional condition is easy to add.